# How to calculate the average-case complexity of an algorithm that finds the biggest and second-biggest number?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm still struggling to understand how to calculate the average-case complexity of my algorithms - probably due the fact I lack some fundamentals on probability.

I have an algorithm that should find the biggest and second-biggest number. A sample written in JavaScript:

```js
/**
 * @param nums - array of numbers
 * @param n - array length
 */
function findBiggest(nums, n) {
  let biggest = nums[0], biggest2 = nums[1];

  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    /* Whenever biggest is changed, biggest2 is also 
     * automatically updated.
     */
    if (nums[i] > biggest) {
      biggest2 = biggest;
      biggest = nums[i];
    }

    else if (nums[i] > biggest2 && nums[i] < biggest)
      biggest2 = nums[i];
  }

  return [biggest, biggest2];
}

/**
 * Input: [5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
 * Output: [5, 4]
 */
```

**Best-case scenario**

I believe the best-case would be a list ordered in descending order (e.g. `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`), as we **wouldn't** have to jump into any condition.

So, considering every instruction, the cost would be `2 + 1 + 1(n - 1)`, being:

- `2` - The first two assignments (`biggest` and `biggest2`);
- `1` - The for assignment (`i = 0`);
- `1(n - 1)` - Total number of times the first `if` condition is checked within the for loop.

Since we ignore constants, we can say the best-case scenario is **O(n)** (linear complexity).

**Worst-case scenario**

At the same time, I believe the worst-case scenario would be a list in ascending order (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`), as we **would** have to enter into the first condition N-1 times.

Considering every instruction, the cost would be `2 + 1 + 3(n - 1)`, being:

- `2` - The first two assignments (`biggest` and `biggest2`);
- `1` - The for assignment (`i = 0`);
- `3(n - 1)` - Considering the `if` check and the two assignments within it.

Since we ignore constants, we can say the worst-case scenario is **O(n)** (linear complexity).

**Please, feel free to correct me if both reasonings above are incorrect. I'm also struggling to understand best-case and worst-case scenarios in some cases.**

However, I don't know how to proceed to calculate the average-case. I can't even imagine what would be the input for the average-case scenario. I know it may require some probability theory, but I don't know how to even start considering it.

1. What input could be considered valid for the average-case scenario?
2. How to calculate the average-case time complexity?

Comment: How do you know if list is ordered in descending order until you do not iterate over it? So your algorithm is `O(length of the list)` in both best and worst scenarios, so the average complexity is same. UPD Got you, it seems you need to calculate average number of instuctions executed

Comment: Thanks, @fas. It makes sense! I was talking about the cost considering every instruction, and not the overall time complexity (which is O(n), indeed). I've updated my question with this information.

Comment: If it's not about complexity, then you need to update your subject line as well.

Comment: We got a confusion here. The final question is about time complexity, indeed. When I told @fas about every instruction, I meant the costs I wrote that initially considered both constants and n - these costs considered constants because they considered every instruction. Then, when transforming them into time complexity, we would ignore any constant and consider only the "n" part, which would give us O(n), indeed.

Comment: However, after reading both fas' comment and kaya3's answer, things become a lot cleaner. Specially @fas' comment's last sentence ("[...] So your algorithm is [...]").

Comment: By the way, I've updated the question one more time to better reflect my questions. My bad. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average case requires no calculation here; it is also linear time, O(n), because the average case must always be between the best and worst cases.

If the average were better than O(n) then it would be better than the best case, and if the average were worse than O(n) then it would be worse than the worst case. Both would be contradictions.

Comment: This question is about number of operations executed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082148/how-to-calculate-the-average-case-complexity-of-an-algorithm-that-finds-the-bigg#comment108062794_61082148, not really about time complexity

Comment: Actually @kaya3's answer is helpful. I've added two more answers to the question's comment section in order to clarify the confusion. By the way, Kaya, thanks: it makes total sense, but somehow I couldn't notice it before.

Comment: @fas - The question clearly asks *"how to calculate the average-case complexity"* and *"How to calculate the average-case time complexity?"* so please read it again.

Comment: @kaya3 I was confused because of comment I provided link to _about the cost considering every instruction, and not the overall time complexity_ (btw which responds to my comment this answer looks similar to) to and how OP calculates constants. My bad